quarkus cant find list of defined beans
I have an Interface and abstract class that implements this interface
public interface ProcessingStrategy {...}

public abstract class AbstractProcessingStrategy implements ProcessingStrategy{...}

and implementations :
@ApplicationScoped
public final class ProcessingStrategy1 extends AbstractProcessingStrategy{}

@ApplicationScoped
public final class ProcessingStrategy2 extends AbstractProcessingStrategy{}

but when I'm injecting it:
@ApplicationScoped
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyServiceImpl implements DispatcherService {
...
    @Inject
    private Instance<ProcessingStrategy> processingStrategies;
   //It's not possible to automatically add a synthetic no-args constructor to an unproxyable bean class. You need to manually add a non-private no-args constructor
    
    //or this
    private final List<ProcessingStrategy> processingStrategies;
    //Unsatisfied dependency for type java.util.List<ProcessingStrategy>

}

Can somebody explain me where is my error?

Either one of the ProcessingStrategyN or the MyServiceImpl classes, which are normal scoped (@ApplicationScoped), does not have a zero-parameter constructor. This is required by CDI. Quarkus can sometimes create a zero-parameter constructor automatically, but not always. It looks like you hit one of those cases, and you need to create a zero-parameter constructor manually. The error message says that pretty clearly.

probably you need to remove final from your beans.
